# How to add reply URI with parameters in Azure AD Redirect URIs?

Tags: azure, redirect, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, adal

When I navigate to my URLs with parameters `http://localhost:4200/meal/3` (number 3 in the URLis the parameter) I get an error that says
"The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application".

But when I try to access the URL that has no parameters `http://localhost:4200` it works fine no errors.

I tried to configure the URL with parameters in "Azure AD Redirect URIs" but it seems that the URLs in "Azure AD Redirect URIs" needs URLs with hard coded parameters value and that will not work I have hundreds of URLs with parameters.

I tried to configure the redirect URLs in Azure AD Redirect URIs to match any parameters value.
`http://localhost:4200/meal/{id}` but it didn't work.

I would like to find a way to configure URLs in Azure AD Redirect URIs so they can match my app URLS parameters without adding hard coded values in the URLs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pass a custom value to Azure AD B2C and need to return that parameter along with the response or with the common Redirect URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62500094/how-can-i-pass-a-custom-value-to-azure-ad-b2c-and-need-to-return-that-parameter)

Answer (score 6):

There is a parameter called state, and the documentation says that you can encode user-specific data to get it back with the token.

> state: A value included in the request that is also returned in the token response. A randomly generated unique value is typically used for preventing cross-site request forgery attacks. The state is also used to encode information about the user's state in the app before the authentication request occurred, such as the page or view they were on.

Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code), potentially that is something you are looking for.

Comment: Hi @kgalic, I can see the value of state parameter in the response URL but it looks encoded.
....&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fmeal%2F3&state=a8b29481-2f49-4f48-a3cf-18d774bed87e&client-request-id=....

with the error  says "The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application"

Comment: By calling: var url= HttpUtility.UrlDecode("test.com?&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fmeal%2F3&state=a3b29481-2f39-4f98-a3cf-18d551bed87e");
You get: test.com?&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/meal/3&state=a3b29481-2f39-4f98-a3cf-18d551bed87e

Comment: now, for example, you can parse that string to get what you want.

Comment: Where I need to call  HttpUtility.UrlDecode() and how is it going to do redirection to that matching url? I run an angular app.

Comment: Angular is not my bread and butter, so please try to find the similar code to c# how to decode url :)

Comment: Thanks, I will try that approach in angular and see if it works.

Comment: Do you have to include the id in the reply url. I think the logic in your app always takes the current URL as the reply url when getting a token. Cant you change the logic to have the same reply url for all requests.

Comment: I need to include id in reply url and id is not the same each time.

Hundreds of meal will end up with ```http:localhost:4200/meal/1...... http:localhost:4200/meal/100``` in Azure AD Redirect URI. 

I am looking for a way to configure Azure AD Redirect URIs to take a custom reply url. Something  like ```http:localhost:4200/meal/:id```

Azure AD Redirect URI is looking for the exact path for exmaple if I have a meal with ID 1 then Azure AD Redirect URI is looking for ```http:localhost:4200/meal/1``` that is not working because I can't put hundreds of meals url in Azure AD Redirect URI

Answer (score 0):

You can set redirect URI to wildcard `http://localhost:4200/*`, then it will redirect you to any URL with `http://localhost:4200/` prefix.

But it is recommended to be avoided due to security implications. Also when using wildcards, query strings and fragments in the redirect URI are stripped. More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url#restrictions-on-wildcards-in-redirect-uris).